# Using group_by and summarize while still taking into account conditions on the whole dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

For each month (DATE_M) in a dataframe, I need to get the sum of AMOUNT that satisfies a double conditions. I need to group_by the SECTOR column then sum the AMOUNT if the following conditions are met: DATE_M is superior or equal to the value in DATE_1 and DATE_M superior or equal to the value in DATE_2. This is not only for the current month. It's an outstanding amount over the whole history of the df.

Here's a small-ish reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(
  DATE_M = structure(c(16374, 16374, 16313, 16313, 
                       16374, 16374, 16343, 16343, 16343, 16343, 16374, 16374, 16374, 
                       16374, 16343, 16343, 16313, 16343, 16343, 16374, 16374, 16313, 
                       16313, 16374, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16313, 16343, 16343, 16374, 
                       16374, 16313, 16313, 16374, 16374, 16343, 16343, 16374, 16313, 
                       16313, 16374, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16374, 16374, 16343, 16343, 
                       16343, 16343, 16343, 16313, 16313, 16313, 16343, 16313, 16374, 
                       16374, 16343, 16313, 16313, 16374, 16313, 16343, 16343, 16374, 
                       16374, 16313, 16343, 16374, 16343, 16343, 16313, 16313, 16343, 
                       16374, 16374, 16374, 16374, 16313, 16374, 16313, 16374, 16374, 
                       16374, 16374, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16374, 
                       16374, 16374, 16343, 16343, 16374, 16343, 16374, 16374, 16374, 
                       16343, 16313, 16343, 16374, 16313, 16374, 16374, 16313, 16343, 
                       16313, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16313, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16313, 
                       16374, 16374, 16343, 16313, 16374, 16343, 16374), class = "Date"), 
  SECTOR = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "AAA", "BBB", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "BBB", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", 
             "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BBB"), 
  AMOUNT = c(2000, 2500, 
             900, 2500, 900, 2300, 1500, 1500, 5000, 9000, 1050, 2500, 
             3000, 3300, 3000, 2000, 2000, 5000, 2000, 1500, 1000, 600, 
             6000, 200, 1000, 2000, 2000, 1000, 3000, 500, 3300, 3000, 
             500, 4000, 6200, 1000, 3000, 1000, 7000, 1500, 1500, 2000, 
             2000, 5000, 1000, 2000, 1000, 1800, 4000, 2000, 800, 1500, 
             20000, 1500, 500, 23500, 1000, 1000, 2500, 500, 5000, 1000, 
             820, 2500, 500, 40, 3000, 550, 10000, 1000, 3500, 1500, 1000, 
             17000, 2500, 7000, 1200, 1000, 7000, 8500, 10000, 5000, 5500, 
             3000, 500, 6600, 1000, 1000, 1500, 800, 2500, 500, 1000, 
             3000, 4000, 600, 2000, 1800, 1100, 500, 1300, 1000, 1000, 
             250, 3850, 3000, 50, 2000, 3400, 500, 1500, 1700, 1600, 5000, 
             1500, 400, 1500, 1000, 2000, 2500, 8000, 700, 3000, 1200, 
             2200, 2000, 1900, 10000), 
  DATE_1 = structure(c(16371, 16353, 
                       16287, 16294, 16374, 16365, 16329, 16321, 16321, 16324, 16367, 
                       16360, 16373, 16353, 16343, 16332, 16287, 16316, 16328, 16345, 
                       16367, 16302, 16311, 16352, 16303, 16351, 16321, 16300, 16331, 
                       16337, 16370, 16363, 16310, 16300, 16367, 16352, 16321, 16317, 
                       16363, 16308, 16302, 16367, 16293, 16346, 16332, 16359, 16371, 
                       16335, 16339, 16324, 16323, 16331, 16303, 16293, 16286, 16316, 
                       16286, 16356, 16372, 16335, 16287, 16288, 16371, 16300, 16332, 
                       16332, 16359, 16350, 16303, 16338, 16370, 16342, 16338, 16303, 
                       16311, 16328, 16344, 16352, 16349, 16356, 16303, 16346, 16289, 
                       16372, 16349, 16344, 16366, 16311, 16359, 16336, 16294, 16356, 
                       16338, 16358, 16367, 16359, 16338, 16325, 16365, 16339, 16359, 
                       16370, 16350, 16321, 16286, 16323, 16374, 16311, 16345, 16356, 
                       16290, 16322, 16310, 16300, 16352, 16317, 16289, 16301, 16373, 
                       16317, 16294, 16366, 16344, 16325, 16303, 16344, 16329, 16356), class = c("IDate", "Date")), 
  DATE_2 = structure(c(16463, 
                       16401, 16318, 16386, 16434, 16489, 16420, 16412, 16412, 16505, 
                       16461, 16391, 16405, 16444, 16434, 16423, 16343, 16344, 16363, 
                       16402, 16549, 16575, 16358, 16717, 16304, 16384, 16681, 16392, 
                       16364, 16398, 16462, 16394, 16402, 16392, 16398, 16359, 16351, 
                       16408, 16450, 16335, 16335, 16374, 16384, 16377, 16363, 16391, 
                       16402, 16517, 16346, 16357, 16414, 16363, 16395, 16318, 16349, 
                       16317, 16568, 16448, 16464, 16426, 16419, 16380, 16463, 16335, 
                       16513, 16696, 16451, 16562, 16394, 16519, 16401, 16372, 16345, 
                       16395, 16343, 16363, 16435, 16444, 16374, 16448, 16335, 16407, 
                       16335, 16402, 16380, 16435, 16489, 16343, 16402, 16366, 16325, 
                       16479, 16399, 16419, 16398, 16451, 16343, 16416, 16458, 16400, 
                       16451, 16401, 16381, 16412, 16317, 16414, 16402, 16343, 16349, 
                       16538, 16384, 16323, 16342, 16331, 16444, 16409, 16416, 16393, 
                       16434, 16349, 16386, 16398, 16435, 16356, 16335, 16374, 16359, 
                       16359), class = c("IDate", "Date"))), 
  row.names = c(NA, -128L), 
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

This is rather easily done with a for loop:

```
test_1 = tibble(SECTOR=NULL, SUM=NULL, DATE_M=as.Date(NULL))

for(DD in df$DATE_M %>% as.character %>% unique){

  tmp <- df %>% 
    group_by(SECTOR) %>% 
    filter(DATE_1 <= DD & DATE_2 >= DD) %>% 
    summarize(SUM = sum(AMOUNT)) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(DATE_M=as.Date(DD))

  test_1 <- bind_rows(test_1, tmp)
}
```

I believe that's the correct result:

```
> test_1 %>% arrange(DATE_M)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  DATE_M     SECTOR    SUM
  <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
1 2014-08-31 AAA     66150
2 2014-08-31 BBB     63000
3 2014-09-30 AAA    106290
4 2014-09-30 BBB     60800
5 2014-10-31 AAA    170860
6 2014-10-31 BBB     63500
```

I tried instead using dplyr, mostly for speed. The real df is millions of row long, there are more conditions and the for loop takes forever.

I tried a very intuitive solution, but it gives the wrong result. Because we use `group_by(DATE_M)`, dplyr starts by applying a sort of filter and ignores all the rows for which the current value is not in DATE_M. As if we started by filter on `DD` in the previous code. This is what I tried:

```
test_2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(DATE_M,SECTOR) %>% 
  summarize(SUM = sum(AMOUNT[which(DATE_1 <= DATE_M & 
                                     DATE_2 >= DATE_M)]))
```

The result is (I think) false, with inferior values, given that it misses some rows:

```
> test_2 %>% arrange(DATE_M)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   DATE_M [3]
  DATE_M     SECTOR    SUM
  <date>     <chr>   <dbl>
1 2014-08-31 AAA     66150
2 2014-08-31 BBB     63000
3 2014-09-30 AAA     62690
4 2014-09-30 BBB     13800
5 2014-10-31 AAA    113170
6 2014-10-31 BBB      7500
```

Can someone please help me achieve this without using a (slow) for loop ?

Hopefully the question will make sense. Thanks.

Comment: one option for doing this (which I think could be faster than either your approach or Andy's approach) is to split the dataframe into sectors, then get the pmax of each row for each sector df. Then get sort the values of AMOUNT according to this pmax column. Because you're looking for things greater than or equal to the pmax, you can get every AMOUNT from a row to the last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group_by(DATE_M)` method indeed doesn't seem to do what you're looking for as it seems the `DATE_M` column is in essence independent from the rest of the columns? As in, if the start and end dates also satisfy inclusion for a `DATE_M` which doesn't appear in the same row, you still want them summed with the the other rows that match that condition?

There are several possible ways of doing this - I'll compare four here for speed:

- your for loop (`for_way()`)
- `purrr::map` which is tidier but likely not faster (`map_way()`)
- `expand_grid` to get a full dataframe of all per-row comparisons (`super_long_way()`)
- `data.table` as a faster alternative for big data frames (`dt_way()`)

I've done this on a simulated 100,000-row dataset, with `DATE_M` split off as a separate set of unique months to test for (some steps in each may not be strictly necessary but have made sure all four results are identical):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  SECTOR = sample(c("AAA", "BBB"), 100000, replace = TRUE),
  AMOUNT = sample(1000:9000, 100000, replace = TRUE),
  DATE_1 = sample(ymd("2014-01-01"):ymd("2014-12-31"), 100000, replace = TRUE) |> as.Date(),
  DATE_2 = DATE_1 + sample(20:60, 100000, replace = TRUE)
)

DATE_M <- ymd("2014-01-01") + months(0:11)

for_way <-
  function() {
    test_1 = tibble(SECTOR = NULL,
                    SUM = NULL,
                    DATE_M = as.Date(NULL))
    
    
    for (DD in DATE_M) {
      tmp <- df %>%
        group_by(SECTOR) %>%
        filter(DATE_1 <= DD & DATE_2 >= DD) %>%
        summarize(SUM = sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
        mutate(DATE_M = as.Date(DD))
      
      test_1 <- bind_rows(test_1, tmp)
    }
    
    test_1
  }

map_way <- function() {
  DATE_M %>% 
    map(\(DD) {
      df %>%
        group_by(SECTOR) %>%
        filter(DATE_1 <= DD & DATE_2 >= DD) %>%
        summarize(SUM = sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
        mutate(DATE_M = as.Date(DD))
    }) |> 
    reduce(bind_rows) %>%
    select(DATE_M, SECTOR, SUM)
  
}


super_long_way <- function() {
  
  tibble(DATE_M) |>
    expand_grid(df) |>
    group_by(DATE_M, SECTOR) %>%
    summarize(SUM = sum(AMOUNT[which(DATE_1 <= DATE_M &
                                       DATE_2 >= DATE_M)]), .groups = "drop")
  
}

library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(df)

dt_way <- function() {
  
  lapply(DATE_M, \(DD){
    dt[dt[, .I[DATE_1 <= DD & DATE_2 >= DD], by = .(SECTOR)]$V1, 
           .(SUM = sum(AMOUNT)), keyby = .(SECTOR)][, `:=`(DATE_M = as.Date(..DD))]
  }) %>%
    rbindlist() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    select(DATE_M, SECTOR, SUM)
  
}



# All give the same results:
# for_way()
# map_way()
# super_long_way()
# dt_way()

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(for_way(), map_way(), super_long_way(), dt_way(), times = 100, check = "equivalent")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>              expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#>         for_way() 160.3486 178.0511 202.83757 192.5698 214.9194 313.6742   100
#>         map_way() 165.5709 181.3580 206.39011 194.2887 225.6654 314.0634   100
#>  super_long_way()  74.3093  94.2489 138.58590 152.7153 164.2177 234.6803   100
#>          dt_way()  64.3447  74.6397  87.02955  81.6293  92.8857 163.1749   100
#>  cld
#>  a  
#>  a  
#>   b 
#>    c
```

It seems that `super_long_way()` and `dt_way()` are the fastest, with `data.table` winning out as a convenient way of doing it with big data.

Tip in case useful: I'm not super-fluent with `data.table` syntax, but I tend to use `dtplyr` to build this for me. The `Call` part returned gives you the `data.table` translation of your tidyverse stack:

```r
library(dtplyr)

DD <- DATE_M[1]

df |> 
  lazy_dt() |> 
  group_by(SECTOR) %>%
  filter(DATE_1 <= DD & DATE_2 >= DD) %>%
  summarize(SUM = sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
  mutate(DATE_M = as.Date(DD))
#> Source: local data table [2 x 3]
#> Call:   `_DT1`[`_DT1`[, .I[DATE_1 <= DD & DATE_2 >= DD], by = .(SECTOR)]$V1, 
#>     .(SUM = sum(AMOUNT)), keyby = .(SECTOR)][, `:=`(DATE_M = as.Date(..DD))]
#> 
#>   SECTOR    SUM DATE_M    
#>   <chr>   <int> <date>    
#> 1 AAA    584957 2014-01-01
#> 2 BBB    581739 2014-01-01
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

Comment: you could always `bench::mark` it :-)

Comment: Thanks for having a look. You understood right: DATE_M is actually rather independant from the rest of the columns. In that context, it's possible that there is no better solution. And purrr::map is indeed tidier. Unfortunately, it's not faster than a for loop.

Comment: I've been experimenting with some hopefully faster ways - will update code shortly...

Comment: Thanks for the work you put in, as well as for the tip. The DT grammar is not very intuitive to me either.
I went for the DT solution. In my case, the running time has been almost halved, which is significant.